# Doctrine Entity not being included inside the Doctrine Events callback

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have Entities with One-to-Many relationship

`TransactionItem -- has many --> Payments`

**EDIT: included the mapping files**

Payment.yml mapping file

```
Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\Payment\Payment:
    type: entity
    table: payments
    repositoryClass: Akademia\Institution\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\Payment\DoctrinePaymentRepository

    id:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 36

    fields:
        date:
            type: datetime

        amount:
            type: decimal
            precision: 11
            scale: 2


    manyToOne:
        transactionItem:
          targetEntity: Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\TransactionItem
          inversedBy: payments
          joinColumn:
            name: transaction_item_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

TransactionItem.yml mapping

```
Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\TransactionItem:
    type: entity
    table: transaction_items
    repositoryClass: Akademia\Institution\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\DoctrineTransactionItemRepository

    id:
        id:
            type: string
            length: 36

    fields:
        productId:
            type: string
            column: product_id

        productType:
            type: string
            column: product_type

        description:
            type: string

        quantity:
            type: integer

        price:
            type: decimal
            precision: 11
            scale: 2

        discount:
            type: decimal
            precision: 11
            scale: 2

        paid:
            type: boolean

        remarks:
            type: string
            nullable: true

    manyToOne:
        transaction:
            targetEntity: Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\Transaction
            inversedBy: lineItems
            joinColumn:
                name: transaction_id
                referencedColumnName: id

    oneToMany:
        payments:
            targetEntity: Akademia\Institution\Sales\Domain\Model\Payment\Payment
            mappedBy: transactionItem
            cascade: ['persist']
            fetch: EAGER
```

when Im calling

```
$transactionItem->pay($amount, $date);
$entityManager->persist($transactionItem);
$entityManager->flush();
```

**TransactionItem.php**

```
public function pay($amount, \DateTime $date = null)
{
        $payment = new Payment(
            Uuid::uuid4()->toString(),
            $this,
            $amount,
            $date ?? new \DateTime());

        $this->payments[] = $payment;
}
```

Im expecting that I can get the `TransactionItem` on doctrine callbacks here:

services.yml

```
services:
    app.doctrine_event_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Event\DomainEventListener
        arguments: ["@app.domain_event_dispatcher"]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }

    app.domain_event_dispatcher:
        class: AppBundle\Event\DefaultEventDispatcher
```

The listener:

```
 class DomainEventListener
    {
        private $entities = array();

        /** @var DomainEventDispatcher */
        private $dispatcher;

        public function __construct(DomainEventDispatcher $dispatcher)
        {
            $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        }

        public function postPersist($event)
        {
            $this->keepAggregateRoots($event);
        }

        public function postUpdate($event)
        {
            $this->keepAggregateRoots($event);
        }

        public function postRemove($event)
        {
            $this->keepAggregateRoots($event);
        }

        public function postFlush($event)
        {
            /** @var AggregateRoot $entity */
            VarDumper::dump($this->entities);die();
            foreach ($this->entities as $entity) {
                foreach ($entity->releaseEvents() as $anEvent) {
                    $this->dispatcher->dispatch($anEvent);
                }
            }

            $this->entities = array();
        }

        private function keepAggregateRoots($event)
        {
            $entity = $event->getEntity();
            if (!($entity instanceof AggregateRoot)) {
                return;
            }

            $this->entities[] = $entity;
        }
    }
```

but when dumping the captured entities on the postFlush `VarDumper::dump($this->entities);`

Im just getting empty array result.

NOTE:
**`TransactionItem` extends `AggregateRoot` but Payment does not**

but at least Im expecting `TransactionItem` to be present.

**Does just adding child relationships will not include it in the doctrine events?**

**How to manually tell doctrine that `TransactionItem` should be present in the postFlush event?**

**EDIT: Dumping inside postUpdate is not being called.**

```
public function postUpdate($event)
    {
        $this->keepAggregateRoots($event);
        VarDumper::dump('Inside postUpdate');
        VarDumper::dump($this->entities);die();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure these methods are called at all? It seems you're creating an event subscriber, not even listener to me.

Comment: I guess so, since calling `VarDumper::dump('Im inside postPersist')` inside the postPersist event works as well as the posted code inside the postFlush.

I'll edit the post to include the services.yml config

Comment: And does the event `postFlush` contain the entities?

Comment: no, Im getting empty array. Even dumping inside the postPersist leads to empty array. I suspect its because Im just adding child entity on TransactionItem and not changing any other fields (just guessing)

Comment: I think you're right. postUpdate is not being called. But why?

Comment: Doc says: *The postUpdate event occurs after the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE statement*. I think when you're adding items to the collection that's not an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127606/discussion-between-daskul-and-martin).  SO discourage extended comment discussions ;)